# Upload Image in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-core

I want to upload image in "wwwroot/uploads/img" folder but i get error.I wrote the following code:

**Create View :**

```
@model imageuploader.Models.Employee

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Create">

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="LastName" Class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="ImageName" type="file" Class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Model :**

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    private readonly RegisterDBContext _context;
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _appEnvironment;


    public EmployeeController(RegisterDBContext context, IHostingEnvironment appEnvironment)
    {

        _context = context;
        _appEnvironment = appEnvironment;
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Employee emp)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
            foreach (var Image in files)
            {
                if (Image != null && Image.Length > 0)
                {
                    var file = Image;
                    //There is an error here
                    var uploads = Path.Combine(_appEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads\\img");
                    if (file.Length > 0)
                    {
                        var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, fileName), FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                            emp.BookPic = fileName;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            _context.Add(emp);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
        }
        return View(emp);
    }
```

When i click on submit button i get an error (error line is marked), how can i upload image or file in Specified path?

**Error:**

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

imageuploader.Controllers.EmployeeController+<Create>d__2.MoveNext() in EmployeeController.cs

                        var uploads = Path.Combine(_appEnvironmen.WebRootPath, "uploads\\img\\");
```

How can i upload image correctly in Specified path?

Comment: Where do you initialize `_appEnvironment` ? Is it `NULL` ?

Comment: @Shyju I updated my question

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your code and find out what is `NULL`

Comment: @Shyju I put a breakpoint in action and `ImageName` in model and `_appEnvironment` is null !!

Comment: as per your form , you are posting to home controller. but  your code shows you are initializing `appEnvironment` in employee controller !

Comment: @Shyju Oh, sorry, because this is a question of an example, not just my real project. I edited it

Comment: Your exception says your code is crashing in `HomeController`. But you are saying you  are posting to EmployeeController. If your controller has the constructor to initialize the `_appEnvironment` variable from the injected `IHostingEnvironment` implementation, it will not be `NULL`

Comment: @Shyju oh thanks i initial _appEnvironment bad in my real projetc. If you can reply, I will mark it as the correct answer

Comment: you can self answer

Comment: Also there is a good tutorial from `Upload and save image in asp.net core` here https://aspcore.ir/upload-and-save-file-in-asp-net-mvc-core/ [link]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Solved it. I understood i initial bad

> _appEnvironment

in Constructor.
With repeated edits, all of the codes in question are currently correct.

Thanks @Shyju user.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to upload an image in C# Asp.net core Web Application 2.1 MVC:

First I'm assuming you've created a model, added to db and now working in the controller.

I've created a Person model
[person model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKyfO.png)

For create get:

```
 //Get : Person Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

post Action (please see screen shot)
[create post action method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xenpg.png)

Finally the view
[Create View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Q1C.png)

Project Output:
[Here is the output of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca8Jr.png)

Comment: Don't be afraid to post longer code here as text. Making it into an image makes it harder to copy/edit.

Comment: It's better to host the images here on Stack Overflow than a third party service (ensures they will remain available).