# asp.net core file upload always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been trying to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2) example in the documentation to allow a file to be uploaded to my controller, it does hit my action, but it always comes through as null.

**My view model**

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Data" asp-action="ImportAdditionalCodes">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <p>Upload import data:</p>
            <input type="file" name="files" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
            <button type="button" id="btnCancelUploadData">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**My Controller action**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ImportAdditionalCodes(IFormFile file)
{
    //file is always null here!!!
    if (file?.Length > 0)
    {
        JsonSerializer js = new JsonSerializer();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(ms);

            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(ms))
            {
                CommodityAdditionalCodeTypeDto[] codes= (CommodityAdditionalCodeTypeDto[]) js.Deserialize(streamReader, typeof(CommodityAdditionalCodeTypeDto[]));
            }
        }
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: you can use this question. There is a good tutorial In this link.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47185920/upload-image-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Small typo. Instead of

```
<input type="file" name="files" >
```

Write:

```
<input type="file" name="file" >
```

You can also access send files using `HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;`

Answer (score 1):

You can also skip the name attribute inside input tag. Like this -

```
<input asp-for="MyFile">
```

Where the corresponding ViewModel is

```
public class FileUploadViewModel
{
    public IFormFile MyFile{ get; set; }
}
```

It will know that input *type* is file (seeing the IFormFile type) and will automatically add *name* attribute to "MyFile".